# Как вызвать onclick в апострофе?

Tags: javascript, html

у меня такая проблема: есть функция, которая принимает только строку и ничего кроме нее. Для вывода нужного HTML-кода я использовал этот способ:

```js
    let balCont = '';
    
    ... = .map(c => { 
    
    const test = (text) => {
        alert(text);
    }
    
    balCont = (`
        <div class="balloon__content">
            <iframe width="400" height="300"
                src=${c.link}?controls=0&autoplay=1"
                frameBorder="0" allow="accelerometer; 
                clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
                allowFullScreen>
            </iframe>
    
            <div class="balloon__text">Description</div>
                <div class="balloon__link__item" 
                    onclick="test('123')"
                >
                    Move to ${c.description}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    `);
    
    }
```

Обращаю внимание,что все это написано в апострофах.

Проблема в том, что onclick реагирует только на такие функции как: alert(), console.log(), но не на кастомные функции.

Вопрос: как добавить свою функцию в onclick?

Comment: А разве test('123') не кастомная функция? Или это она не срабатывает? В какой области видимости располагается Ваша кастомная функция? В консоль что-то выводит? Разместите [минимальный самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), который воспроизводит ошибку, здесь или на [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция `const test` определена как локальная в анонимной функции, передаваемой в `map`. `onclick` выполняется в глобальной области видимости, где `test` не видна.

```
... = .map(c => { 

  balCont = (`
    ...
    onclick="test('123')"
    ...
  `);
});

// not inside any function:
const test = (text) => {
    alert(text);
}
```